# How to pass variables from python to php?

Tags: php, python

I am doing one project where I am reading data from google sheet in python .Here I passed the variables from php script to python and then in python I am doing some computation .Now I want to send those variables back to php script from python. How do I do that ?

```
username=sys.argv[1]
print(username)

for row in range(1,100):
    if wks.cell(row,2).value== username:
        n=row
        break

print(n)        



apti=0

if wks.cell(n,4).value == "1060":
    apti+=1

if wks.cell(n,5).value == "20 yrs":
    apti+=1 

if wks.cell(n,6).value == "25":
    apti+=1

if wks.cell(n,7).value == "250":
    apti+=1

if wks.cell(n,8).value == "6":
    apti+=1

if wks.cell(n,9).value == "12":
    apti+=1

if wks.cell(n,10).value == "48":
    apti+=1

if wks.cell(n,11).value == "1 and 2 only":
    apti+=1

if wks.cell(n,12).value == "41":
    apti+=1



if apti==9:
    print('success')
else:
    print ('Fail')  

count=10
```

Now I want to send the value of count variable back to the php script

Comment: May I ask why you're not just sticking to one language?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. I think you are using Google API to read cell values and do some computation. What I suggest is you write the final our value(s) to the sheet and then try using php interface to read from the sheet. So the google sheet acts as database for you.

```
# At the end of python case, update sheet with final value
sheet.update_cell(...)
```

To use php to read from the updated google sheet, refer to documentation here : https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php

Hope this helps !